# Unwanted white space in Robot catenate statements

Tags: concatenation, robotframework, removing-whitespace

I'm finding unwanted whitespace in the output of a `Catenate` in Robot Framework.
First I use a keyword I've defined:

Next line should be taking in a Python datetime and an integer. Should be returning a string

```
${to_due_date}=    Delta Month    ${todaysDate}    1
```

Then I try to strip out the leading/trailing space from the output when using catenate:

```
${to_string}=    Catenate    To Due Date:    ${to_due_date.strip()}
```

but the output of this when I send it to console, shows the whitespace in there:

```
To Due Date: 24 Feb 2017
```

I've also tried building up the string using Strip String, but with no success.

Is there a more effective way of using catenate that doesn't have whitespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the space between ":" and "24"? That's exactly how the `Catenate` keyword works: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Catenate ... "By default, items are catenated with spaces..."
Use `${to_string}=    Catenate    SEPARATOR=    To Due Date:    ${to_due_date.strip()}` if you need.

Comment: that seems to strip only the first whitespace - the trailing space is still there: To Due Date:24 Feb 2017 ;

Comment: Yes, exactly. That omits only the space between two strings to be catenated. If you want also omit spaces in the date string, use for instance `${to_due_date.replace(" ", "")}` instead of that `strip()`. But I'm still not sure what exactly you need.

Comment: Thanks, that is fine - it was the leading and trailing whitespaces and not those within the date itself.